# How to repair damage to finished fibreboard

Tags: cabinets, finishing, damage

Not sure exactly what happened, but there is now a dent in the  bottom of one of my IKEA cabinet doors, which is Fibreboard covered with some kind of enamel or plastic.

[image]

I'm wondering if there is any way to repair this damage rather than replacing the door (this is the discontinued line and replacement parts are harder to find and more expensive).

As a result of the damage, this part actually bulges out slightly. I do have matching enamel paint to cover the chipped surface, but ideally I'd also like to get the surface flat again before I paint it.

Comment: It's a bottom door so it isn't as noticeable. If I can get the dent to disappear I'm less worried about how the finish will look when done.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like someone opened the door with an object in the way. It's going to be very difficult to replicate a factory-applied vinyl coating as a DIY project. I'd contact IKEA about a replacement, or look for coordinating replacement doors from a local cabinet clearance outlet.

Otherwise, I'd shave out the loose, cracked, and bulged material with a sharp utility knife, then apply high-quality wood filler (Plastic Wood bonds very well and dries hard). Mask before sanding to minimize the impact to the surrounding area.

Comment: Meant to post this under your answer; not sure why it ended up under my question: It's a bottom door so it isn't as noticeable. If I can get the dent to disappear I'm less worried about how the finish will look when done.